# RStudio: Pandoc.exe has stopped working (Error 5)

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, pandoc, ioslides

I just tried to knit a very simple .Rmd document with output set to isoslides; but I'm getting an error with pandoc (Error 5).

````
---
title: "Test"
date: "April 3, 2018"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Slide with R Output

```{r cars, echo = TRUE}
summary(cars)
```
````

When I choose "Knit", I get a pop-up box:

[image]

And some error messages:

```
output file: delete.knit.md

"C:/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS delete.utf8.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output delete.html --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --variable transition=0.4 --template "C:\Users\myusername\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\rmarkdown\rmd\ioslides\default.html" --include-in-header "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpmEmO8h\rmarkdown-str17e07fd6873.html" --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" 
"C:/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS delete.utf8.md --to ioslides_presentation.lua --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output "C:\Users\newtoner\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpmEmO8h\ioslides-output17e0613812ce.html" --slide-level 2 
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 5
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS delete.utf8.md --to ioslides_presentation.lua --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpmEmO8h\ioslides-output17e0613812ce.html" --slide-level 2' had status 5 
Execution halted
```

I've tried reinstalling the rmarkdown package using devtools, restarting my computer, and searching this on google... no luck yet. I'd rather not reinstall RStudio if I can help it.

My session info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.15     digest_0.6.15    withr_2.1.1.9000 rprojroot_1.3-2  R6_2.2.2         backports_1.1.2  magrittr_1.5     git2r_0.12.1    
 [9] evaluate_0.10.1  httr_1.3.1       stringi_1.1.6    curl_3.1         rmarkdown_1.9.8  devtools_1.13.2  tools_3.4.1      stringr_1.3.0   
[17] yaml_2.1.18      compiler_3.4.1   memoise_1.0.0    htmltools_0.3.6  knitr_1.20
```

Comment: This might help https://community.rstudio.com/t/cannot-knit-rmd-file-pandoc-error/614/4

Comment: I tried running RStudio as an administrator, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running RStudio as an administrator and also reinstalling the rmarkdown package, and a few other things.

I didn't want to reinstall RStudio because my network is super slow (1.5 hrs to download the .exe). I did end up having to uninstall RStudio. I uninstalled Pandoc as well (which was V2.1.1) and then reinstalled RStudio.

It works now. Sigh!